# Why can I vote on closed question?

Tags: discussion

When we vote to close a question , we doesn't allow question to get answers,but we can upvote or downvote this question. When a question is not allowed to get answers, should we also not stop it from getting votes?

Also why should one vote on a question which is not valuable?

Comment: I think this will be an excellent question for meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CRags Take look at below answer and a link in first sentence. This ques was asked in meta before and I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 7):

There's background [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83798/165581).

In an ideal situation, question closure is a temporary state. Either the closed question will be improved and reopened, or it will get deleted.

If the question is reopened, that's great! The asker deserves whatever rep changes come along with the votes -- even the ones from when it was closed. If the question gets deleted, all votes disappear anyway along with their respective reputation changes, so it's like it never happened.

But in the meantime, it doesn't hurt anything to vote on closed questions. (In fact, if I were a user with 500 rep, say, and I disagreed with a question's closing, the only action I'd be able to take is upvoting, since I wouldn't have reopen privileges yet.)

Comment: Closed questions will only be deleted automatically when they received little attention and no votes before the closure. If they have votes, they will stay. The same is true for closed and massively downvoted questions, which got enough attention. I think we should go over the last category.

Comment: Except for closed duplicate questions